# R: least number of sets with decimal numbers on some condition?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, partition, enumerate

Consider

```
> data.frame(n=runif(6),m=1:6)
            n  m
1  0.44000000  1
2  0.12102262  2
3  0.95483015  3
4  0.35628753  4
5  0.55000000  5
6  0.50189420  6
```

where you want to form the least number of sets having decimal numbers where the sum of numbers is less than 1.

*Example trial to find the partions, not necessarily optimal way to find the partitions (particularly with bigger sets)*

> For example, a partition is a set of number `3` because it is less than one i.e. `0.95483015<1`. Then other partition is a set of `5` and `1` because  `0.55+0.44<1`. And rest numbers go to third partitions such that
>
> 1. partition: 3
> 2. partition: 5,1
> 3. partition: 2,4,6

now I have a big list of numbers like that which I need to make into least number of partitions or least number of sets having decimal numbers.

**Does there exist some R package to find partitions with some optimal criteria like the least number of partitions with some condition?**

Comment: This looks to me as a slight variation to the bounded knapsack problem, since you use each number in column ``n`` once, so you should have a PTAS solution to it. I dont know of a package that implements it out of the box, but the problem is well studied so mb you can adapt a pseudo algorithm. HTH

Comment: @PlamenPetrov or perhaps there is some subset function where I can specify a condition? Found this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adagio/adagio.pdf, no exp w it yet -- `adagio::subsetsum(numbs, t=1)` seems to work, testing, little bit slow with large set of numbers.

Comment: Based on documentation, u likely want to do ``adagio:subsetsum(numbs, t=1, methon = 'dynamic')``

Comment: @PlamenPetrov correct, `dynamic` option makes it far faster. What I see is that adagio finds the partitions where the sum is exactly 1, instead of 1 or below, it would be super useful to define some threshold to tradeoff for some extra speed. How would you implement the bound?

Comment: Why not define something like ``tol = 1e-10`` and then do ``t = 1 - tol``, do you have any concerns?

Comment: @PlamenPetrov lost by the latter, do you mean? `t=1-tol:=1-(1e-10)=11-1e`? What is the `e`? Some sort of epsilon to specify the border?

Comment: Looks to me more like **bin packing** than assignment or knapsack problem. Not easy to find optimal solutions, but simple heuristics are available.

Comment: Oh, yeah, of course you are right, it is bin packing, good catch. Regarding the tolerance, it is scientific notation s.t. ``tol = 1e-4 = 0.0001``